# Trying to use SUMPRODUCT to identify unique values based on two additional conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am having some difficulty with this formula and I am hoping someone can help.  I have searched extensively everywhere I can think of and can't find an answer pertaining directly to this issue.  I have data in a spreadsheet table tracking employee assigned tasks and am focusing on three fields: the employee name (Employee Name), the date the employee was assigned a task (Employee Assigned Date) and the month and year the employee was assigned the task (Task Month Year).

I am trying to identify the unique assigned dates for a given employee in a given month/year.  So in the example below, John Smith would return three unique dates for March 2017, since 03/05/2017 and 03/14/2017 repeat.

```
Employee Name        Employee Assigned Date        Task Month Year
Paul Martin          03/01/2017                    March 2017
James Smith          03/05/2017                    March 2017
James Smith          03/05/2017                    March 2017
James Smith          03/06/2017                    March 2017
James Smith          03/14/2017                    March 2017
James Smith          03/14/2017                    March 2017
```

The formula that I have come up with is as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table2[Employee Name]=”James Smith”)*(Table2[Task Month Year]")=”March 2017”/(COUNTIF(Table2[Employee Assigned Date],Table2[Employee Assigned Date]&"")))
```

I have stripped out some pieces of the formula that convert month date to text, etc. so the issue is not around that.  If I sumproduct the employee name and task month year section by itself, I get the correct answer for the total of James Smith's assigned tasks, five.  If I remove the Employee Name piece I get the correct answer for unique dates in March 2017 for all employees, four.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, I'm assuming I am doing something stupid but I've been working on this for hours and can't seem to find the solution on my own.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you specify what kind of output you are looking for and how it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNTIF` will return the wrong values in your suggested formula because the name criteria isn't included in that part. One solution is to include the name criteria in an expanded `COUNTIFS` like this:

`=SUM(IFERROR((Table2[Task Month Year]="March 2017")/(Table2[Employee Name]="James Smith")/COUNTIFS(Table2[Employee Assigned Date],Table2[Employee Assigned Date],Table2[Employee Name],"James Smith"),0))`

confirm with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

.....or you can fall back on the old `FREQUENCY` approach, i.e.

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Table2[Task Month Year]="March 2017", IF(Table2[Employee Name]="James Smith",IF(Table2[Employee Assigned Date]<>"",MATCH(Table2[Employee Assigned Date],Table2[Employee Assigned Date],0)))),ROW(Table2[Employee Assigned Date])-MIN(ROW(Table2[Employee Assigned Date]))+1),1))`

also confirm with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

Both should give the same answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by removing duplicates. If you need to retain the original data, then of course copy and paste it to a new tab first.

In the Data tab, select Remove Duplicates. Then in the pop-up box, make sure you select all 3 of your columns, presumably A, B and C from the way you laid it out above. This will make sure that duplicates matching all 3 columns will be removed, giving you a list of unique assignment dates per employee, per month/year combination.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  Unfortunately this formula is contained in a real-time dashboard so I need it to calculate on the fly as new employee data is entered.  I appreciate the help though!